# Merging these 2 batch queries?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to merge the following batch files.  There must be an easier way for me to detect what version of Java is currently installed, if it is the latest goto End if not install the latest version.

I would love to the the for/f command and found this also online:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set VERSION7="1.7.0_25"
for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (
@echo Output: %%g
set JAVAVER=%%g
)
set JAVAVER=%JAVAVER:"=%
@echo Output: %JAVAVER%

for /f "delims=. tokens=1-3" %%v in ("%JAVAVER%") do (
@echo Major: %%v
@echo Minor: %%w
@echo Build: %%x
)
endlocal
```

**My current script to install Java runtime is:**

```
IF exist %windir%\gpologs\jre_1.7.21.x86.txt ( goto eof ) ELSE ( goto Q1 )

:Q1 
Reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86417025FF}" 
if "%ErrorLevel%"=="0" ( goto eof ) ELSE ( goto Q2 )

:Q2 
Reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83217025FF}" 
if "%ErrorLevel%"=="0" ( goto eof ) ELSE ( goto Q3 ) 

:Q3 
Reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83217021FF}" 
if "%ErrorLevel%"=="0" ( goto eof ) ELSE ( goto Install ) 

:Install 
msiexec /i "\\Sharename\GPOInstalls\Java\Java 1.7.0_21 x86\jre1.7.0_21.msi" /qn
if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 (
    >>"\Sharename\gpolog\jre_1.7.21.x86.csv" echo "%computername%","%date%","%Time%","%ErrorLevel%","Java Runtime 1.7.0_21x86 Installed"
    >>"%windir%\GpoLogs\jre_1.7.21.x86.txt" echo "Java Runtime 1.7.0_21x86 Installed"
) else (
    >>"\\Sharename\gpolog\JavaInstallErrors.csv" echo "%computername%","%date%","%Time%","%ErrorLevel%","Error trying to install Java 1.7_21x86"
)

:eof
```

How can I use the first code (for /f) to search for the java version if it does not meet the latest go to my :Install section in the second part of the code?

I do not know how to include this in the for/f section.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What about `java -version`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to suggest a solution with [wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) and [grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm). Explanation is in the comments:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL

REM get the latest Java version from the Oracle web site
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%a IN ('wget -O- "http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u-relnotes-515228.html" 2^>nul^|grep -io "Changes in [^<]*"') DO (
    IF NOT DEFINED JAVA_latest SET "JAVA_latest=%%~a"
)

REM get the current installed Java version
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| find /i "version"') do SET "JAVA_current=%%~a"

REM print the results
ECHO Java versions: latest: %JAVA_latest%, current installed: %JAVA_current%

REM compare the versions, exit if equal
IF "%JAVA_latest%"=="%JAVA_current%" (ECHO Latest Java version already installed.&GOTO:eof)

REM put your install code here
ECHO here goes your code
```

Comment: Hi Endoro, thanks this may be one for when I have a little time on my hands, regarding Wget/Grep do I need to download the Sources or Full Install?

Comment: @Mikoyan no, there are binaries. You don't need to compile something.

Comment: But surely I need to have this wget/grep on system to call this utility? If I type in wget /? I get nothing.

Comment: Also is there a way I can simply use the for/f command which is at the top of this page. Basically I just to check the java output if is not equal to 25 (latest) goto :Install

Comment: path to `wget` is on x86 `"%programfiles%\gnuwin32\bin\wget"`, for help type `wget --help`. to get the current java version enter simply `for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| find /i "version"') do @echo "%%~a"`. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Endoro